# Trying to temporarily store objects in an NSMutableArray in a Singleton class for later use in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I have a Singleton class that has two methods:

```
- (void)saveString:(NSString *)stringObject {

    [[[Singleton sharedInstance] stringArray] addObject:stringObject];
}

- (NSArray *)getArrayContents {

    return [[Singelton sharedInstance] stringArray];
}
```

Here is the implementation code of my Singleton class:

```
static Singleton *sharedSingleton = nil;

+ (Singleton *) sharedInstance {

    if (sharedSingleton == nil) {
        sharedSingleton = [[super alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedSingleton;
}
```

I have two View Controllers (vcA, and vcB) in my application.  What I am trying to do is temporarily store the data from vcA, so that the data inside stringArray will be accessible later to vcB.

Here is the code that vcA uses to store the data:

```
[[Singleton sharedInstance] saveString:stringName];
```

Later in the lifecycle of the application, vcB calls the Singleton class to retrieve the values from the NSMutableArray:

```
NSArray *newArray = [[Singleton sharedInstance] getArrayContents];
       for (NSString *test in newArray) {
           NSLog(@"Here are the contents of the array %@", test);
       }
```

Unfortunately, when I make the call in vcB to print the contents of the Array, there is no output because the array is empty, despite the fact that values are added to the array.  What is it I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How did you implement the singleton?

Comment: Showing your singleton code will help people identify the problem.

Comment: The methods at the top is from my Singleton class (saveString, getArrayContents).

Comment: I've added the implementation code of my Singleton class in my question.

Comment: Did you initialize `stringArray`?

Comment: That might be the problem.  Where would I do that?

Comment: Usually in singleton's `init`.

Comment: Is that legit to allocate `super` rather than `self`?  Seems to me that space for any fields in the singleton class would not be allocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, these two methods should probably use `self`, not sharedInstance:

```
- (void)saveString:(NSString *)stringObject {

    [[self stringArray] addObject:stringObject];
}

- (NSArray *)getArrayContents {

    return [self stringArray];
}
```

Second, there’s no point in having a `getArrayContents` method when you already have `stringArray`, and `get` as a prefix is usually reserved for methods that take a parameter to be copied into, anyhow.

Third, I don’t see you initializing stringArray anywhere, so unless there’s code missing, it’s nil and it’s staying nil. Maybe try:

```
+ (Singleton *) sharedInstance {

    if (!sharedSingleton) {
        sharedSingleton = [[self alloc] init];
        sharedSingleton.stringArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return sharedSingleton;
}
```

Assuming stringArray is declared something like:

```
@property (readwrite, strong) NSMutableArray *stringArray;
```

Comment: @hot Oh, crap, didn’t notice that, was just copy/pasting. Thanks! It’d happen to work in this case, because nobody implements alloc in their subclasses these days, but it’s still sloppy as heck.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it would work or not.  How does super alloc get the object size?

Comment: It looks at the class, but the class still reports itself as the subclass when you call super. Like, if you call [super description] on a subclass of NSObject, it still returns the description of the subclass, not NSObject itself.

Comment: I'm not so sure.  Might have to try a few scenarios.

Comment: Just call `po [NSView class]` in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

to create `Singleton`

```
+(Singleton *)sharedSingleton {

    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static Singleton *sharedSingleton;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedSingleton = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedSingleton;
}
```

and the `init` method of singleton class

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //@property stringArray
        self.stringArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Other methods of `Singleton`

```
- (void)saveString:(NSString *)stringObject {

    [self.stringArray addObject:stringObject];
}

- (NSArray *)getArrayContents {

    return self.stringArray;
}
```

Comment: Tried to change "singleton" to "singleton" - but edits must be at least six characters!!! That's a daft rule. Apart from that, this is the generally accepted pattern to create a singleton object that everyone should use.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. My code in the singleton looked like this:

```
+ (ReportDataList*)sharedDataArray
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static ReportDataList *shared = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[ReportDataList alloc] init];
        self.rDetailsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}
```

I had incorrectly initialised the array, so it was emptying it when I created a reference to the singleton later in my code. I removed the array initialisation, which is done in the -(id)init method and it worked fine.  So, my code then looked like this:

```
+ (ReportDataList*)sharedDataArray
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static ReportDataList *shared = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[ReportDataList alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.rDetailsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self initWithDummyValues];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"problem initialising array list");
    }
    return self;
}
```